# Getting $_POST array in an AJAX page that is called from a jQuery $.post(...)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Please take a look at [this](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-simple-web-based-chat-application--net-5931). I tried to understand the code but had trouble here:

```
$("#submitmsg").click(function(){   
    var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
    $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
    $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
    return false;
});
```

1. Basically, if you press the `submit` button, you call that
   `post.php` page which does everything inside it, right?
2. Question, why is the `post.php` page not actually loaded even when I
   erased `return false`? I ASSUMED that this is because in my `form`,
   the `action = ""` which means I'm basically reloading the same page.
   Am I right?
3. Afterwards, why didn't the AJAX load that `post.php` page even
   though it's called in `$.post` above? Is it because I AJAX did not actually load the page but instead just does everything in said page without redirecting my current page?

I apologise in advance if my questions seem incoherent and confusing. It would be really nice if someone could advise me and say what I'm getting wrong here (I feel like, a lot).

Form below:

```
<form name="message" action="">
        <input name="usermsg" type="text" id="usermsg" size="63" />
        <input name="submitmsg" type="submit"  id="submitmsg" value="Send" />
</form>
```

`post.php` page below:

```
<?
session_start();

    if(isset($_SESSION['name'])){
        $text = $_POST['text'];

        $fp = fopen("log.html", 'a');
        fwrite($fp, "<div class='msgln'>(".date("g:i A").") <b>".$_SESSION['name']."</b>: ".stripslashes(htmlspecialchars($text))."<br></div>");
        fclose($fp);
    }
?>
```

Is there a way to access the above page while it's being called(is this the correct term?) by the jQuery AJAX? I want to see the `$_POST` variables included inside there when I ran jQuery AJAX by using `echo`.

Comment: You might want to take a look at [preventDefault()](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) to stop your form from being submitted

Comment: Try type="button" instead of type="submit" and it will be fine!

Comment: To access what is returned from the POST request, you need to add a `success` handler to your AJAX call. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/ . To just look at the return, you can see the request and response in your browser's network tab.

Comment: AJAX is a _background_ request, so you don’t “see” anything of it per se; you need to do something with the data, if you want to see anything based on it. Using your browser dev tools, network panel, you can check what values were sent to the server with your request; and if you make any debug outputs inside your server-side script, you can see those in the response to the request there as well.

Comment: @kerbholz @Bernhard That's not the question, though. I can already disable form submission using `return false`.

Comment: @04FS I see. So basically, I'm not loading the page and instead only CALLING the page so that it executes whatever is inside? Even if I `echo 'a'` inside the called file, I won't be able to see it? I'll check that out. If you have the time, could you provide a link so that I can read about checking sent values etc.?

Comment: To see the submitted text immediately you need to append the written data (line that starts by "fwrite") to your html by using jQuery.

Comment: @04FS I see, I've successfully checked the data I output in my AJAX-called file. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, your form will be submitted because you used input submit and your jquery will not be triggered. you can do it using [preventDefault](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) method like this :

```
$("#submitmsg").on('click', function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var clientmsg = $("#usermsg").val();
  $.post("post.php", {text: clientmsg});              
  $("#usermsg").attr("value", "");
  return false;
});
```

You can see what's happening in AJAX file using Chrome Developer Tools (right click > inspect element) then go to Network tab.

Comment: I see. The form is already not submitted using `return false`.

Comment: You can also use <button type="button">Submit</button> to trigger the jquery to avoid submitting the form using html action.

Comment: That's not the question, though.